# Texture looks very bad?

Tags: uv, blender-internal-render-engine

[image]
The texture appears not good on the object. I need it to fit the size.

Comment: Did you set up the uvs and have the texture match the uv size?

Answer (score 1):

From what I see in your screenshot, your UV islands don't fit the scale of your model. This is almost always the case if you didn't apply the scale of your object.

Move the mouse to your 3D viewport, be sure to be in Object Mode, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, which should open the "Apply" menu. Select "Scale".

[image]

After that you need to unwrap your object again to get the exact UV representation of your model.

Comment: No big change. Still the same. Maybe the texture is small ?

Answer (score 0):

Try rescaling some of the UV faces so they have the same proportions as the model. I find it helps a lot when doing a good texture, it takes a little bit of time but the results are good.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Manually...not good at all. It will take long time from me.